# Insert trigger not inserting new rows in other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anyone point out why this insert trigger is not inserting the new rows into the IVRTestB table?

```
  If Object_ID('MyTrig3', 'TR') IS Not Null
  Drop Trigger MyTrig3;
  GO

  Alter Trigger MyTrig3
  On dbo.IVRTest
  After Insert, update
    AS
  Begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  Insert Into [dbo].[IVRTestB]  
  (IVRAID, IVRName, DayNumber, OpenFlag)  
  Select 
     'i.IVRAID', 'i.IVRName', 'i.DayNumber', 'i.OpenFlag'
          From inserted i
      INNER JOIN dbo.IVRTestB b
      On i.IVRAID = b.IVRAID
      END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting every column of `Inserted` into single quotes, you're effectively inserting **string literals** into your destination table - not the column values!

Use this code instead:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[IVRTestB] (IVRAID, IVRName, DayNumber, OpenFlag)  
   SELECT
      i.IVRAID, i.IVRName, i.DayNumber, i.OpenFlag    -- *NO* single quotes here!!!!
   FROM   
      inserted i
   -- change this WHERE clause to insert those rows that AREN'T alredy in IVRTestB !
   WHERE
      i.IVRAID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT IVRAID FROM dbo.IVRTestB)
```

Comment: Agh forgot to remove that when testing, nice, still not inserting into IVRTestB though when I insert a new record into IVRTest.

Comment: I am trying to insert into another table the trigger is on IVRTest and the insert should be on the IVRTestB table.

Comment: @sz1: with the current `INNER JOIN` condition that you have, you will only ever insert rows that *already exist** in your target table (since you're inner joining to `dbo.IVRTestB`). Is that really what you want?

Comment: I just want the new records going into IVRTestB.

Comment: @sz1: but as I said - right now you're **NOT** inserting anything into `IVRTestB` that isn't already in the table... I updated my answer with a new `WHERE` clause that should insert new rows into IVRTestB

Comment: Nice so I always need to specify a condition to check is exists first, that makes sense! thanks

Comment: This should work, if it does not check to see if there is a trigger on table IVRTestB that is preventing the insert.

Comment: the other thing to consider is what do you want to do with records that already exist in table IVRTestB? Do you need to update tehm to the new values?

Comment: Not really but would be handy to append script to keep for ref.

Comment: If I need to update the whole IVRTestB table I can swap the Inserted I to IVRTest i.

Comment: @sz1: I don't see any benefit, really.... the rows that are being inserted are in `Inserted` - why would you want to insert rows from `IVRTest` to `IVRTestB` that have not been inserted with this operation?

Comment: I don't but good to know I can dump the lot if needed. Only the inserted are going across now which is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Alter Trigger MyTrig3
  On dbo.IVRTest
  After Insert
    AS
  Begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
       IF EXISTS ( SELECT  
                      1  
                  FROM  
                      INSERTED  
                  WHERE  
                      INSERTED.DayNumber IS NULL )  
  Insert Into 
  [dbo].[IVRTestB]  
  (IVRAID, 
  IVRName, 
  DayNumber, 
  OpenFlag)  
  Select 
     i.IVRAID,
      i.IVRName, 
      i.DayNumber, 
      i.OpenFlag
          From inserted i
       WHERE  
                 INSERTED.DayNumber IS NULL  
      END
```

Answer (score 0):

Mohan,

You change nearly worked, I just had to change the not nulls to is not null and the alias for inserted to I

```
   Alter Trigger MyTrig3
  On dbo.IVRTest
  After Insert
    AS
  Begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
       IF EXISTS ( SELECT  
                      1  
                  FROM  
                      INSERTED  
                  WHERE  
                      INSERTED.DayNumber IS NOT NULL )  
  Insert Into 
  [dbo].[IVRTestB]  
  (IVRAID, 
  IVRName, 
  DayNumber, 
  OpenFlag)  
  Select 
     i.IVRAID,
      i.IVRName, 
      i.DayNumber, 
      i.OpenFlag
          From inserted i
       WHERE  
                 i.DayNumber IS NOT NULL  
      END
```